# Non-empty cells in Excel Range C#

Tags: c#, excel, range

I want to select all non-empty cells from the current cell to the last cell of the row.

If we use

```
currentRange.End[XlDirection.xlToRight]
```

this is not a good approach when the non-empty cells are not contiguous [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba). For example, cells A1, A2, A3, A5, A6 are not empty, then `RangeA1.End[XlDirection.xlToRight]` only go as far as A3, that is, the last non-empty cell connected to RangeA1.

Another option:

```
CreateRange(currentRange, lastRangePossibleinRow).SpecialCells(...)
```

I have 3 question:

1. `currentRange.End[XlDirection.xlToRight]` seems like an unreliable solution. For example, if currentRange is empty, this will return 1 cell anyway (itself).
2. How do I extend the selection from current cell to the last cell in Row effectively? `CreateRange(currentRange, get_range(currentRange.Row + sheet.Columns.Count.ToString()))` ? Perhaps there is a better solution.
3. How to get a collection of cells in this Range that is not empty? `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants | xlCellTypeFormulas)`  will not work, for example, if non is found, `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` will throw an exception: no cells found.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to VBE, but I think a workaround would be to

1. target a range in which you expect non-blanks
2. iterate through them
3. check if isblank
4. store the col# of the ones that are false in an array in the form `RC[#]`
5. then select just those by `Range("Array(1),Array(2),...").Select` .

Sorry for the pseudocode... and being two months late. =/

Comment: Glad to have your input, and it's never too late to learn something new. ;) Regarding your answer, it's exactly what I want to avoid : iteration and for loop. It would hurt performance, imaging one row or column in Excel which already contains 1 million cells; then multiply that by several rows/columns if I want to check multiple. That is the reason for built-in treatement like .Specialcells I suppose, it gives better performance according to my experience.